# Create meaning backend name in backend service using service name

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

[image]

Instead of the name k8s-b3-31854-5e4818065f5c5f8a, can I specify a more descriptive name when I create a new Ingress?

This is the spec for my Ingress.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: <hostname hidden here>
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: ota
              servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

The K8s ingress resource will use the name you specified under metadata.name. The name of the GCP L7LB will continue to use the generic k8s- name though. The name you assign the resource will appear in the L7LB name, but you can't specify it exactly